# Convert text to quint16

Tags: qt, qstring

I want to convert a `QString` to `quint16`. I'm reading a port number from a `textBox`, and I need to convert it into `quint16` format for my `UDP` socket `writeData()` function.

Is it easier to store the text in a `QByteArray` then convert it? If so, I've only found the modifier `toUint()`, but nothing for `quint16`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Qt docs, `quint16` is just a typedef for `unsigned short` - so you can simply use `QString::toUShort`.

Comment: I tried that. It crashes at runtime when it gets to sending the datagram. If I just put a port number into a quint16, it's fine. But this conversion doesn't work correctly for some reason. this is what I have: quint16 device_Port = devicePort.toUShort(&ok, 10);

Comment: I suppose `ok` is a bool and its value is actually `true` after running this line of code? Did you try to output the values of `devicePort`, `device_Port` and `ok` via a `qDebug()` statement, e.g. `qDebug() << devicePort << device_Port << ok;`? This should print something like `"12345" 12345 true`.

Comment: Yes I did, and I get exactly that: "4595" 4595 true. Still trying to figure out what's going on here... so the error comes when U write to the UDP socket:                 **udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), QHostAddress(newIP), device_Port);**  

newIP is the QString that holds the IP collected from the text input. I know it's reading it correctly because it displays it properly at my output window. Maybe my issue lies not in the conversion to quint16 but in my IP address conversion. Thanks for the help!